# Left join without duplicate rows

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables called `record` and `record_history`. For each record, there could be more than one history. They can be joined by `id` and `record_id`. I want to get all the `record`'s entries with recent `record_history` data. I have created the query like,

```
SELECT rec.id, rec.name, rech1.data AS last_history_data
FROM record rec
LEFT OUTER JOIN record_history rech1 ON (rec.id = rech1.record_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN record_history rech2 ON (rec.id = rech2.record_id AND rech2.ts > rech1.ts)
WHERE rech2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY rec.id DESC
```

Here, I am getting the latest one by `ts`. This works as long as there are no duplicate `ts` entries. If the recent timestamp is repeated in `record_history`, this query returns more than one row for a record. How can we apply the limit here on the left join to restrict duplicate rows?

Comment: you're not selecting anything from rech2?

Comment: @EvanCarroll `rech2` is used here select the first record_history and my need for rech2 is to be `NULL`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless you are in a very old version of Postgres, you don't need the double join. You can get the same result by using a **[`LATERAL` join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html)**.

The duplicate results can be avoided in your method by adding a second condition besides the `rec.id = rech2.record_id`. With the `LATERAL` join method, the use of `LIMIT`  is avoiding it anyway. There can be only 1 row returned from the lateral subquery. We can add a second condition so the choice is deterministic (from the two or more rows with same timestamp):

```
SELECT rec.id, rec.name, rech.data AS last_history_data
FROM record AS rec
     LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL
     ( SELECT rech.data
       FROM record_history AS rech
       WHERE rec.id = rech.record_id
       ORDER BY rech.ts DESC
                -- ,rech.id DESC               -- optional
       LIMIT 1 
     ) AS rech
     ON TRUE
ORDER BY rec.id DESC ;
```

---

Regarding how to do this with the original method (2 joins and `IS NULL` check), you could change the `ON` condition - assuming there is an `id` column in history table so that `(id)` or at least `(ts, id)` is unique:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN record_history rech2 
ON rec.id = rech2.record_id 
   AND (rech2.ts > rech1.ts OR rech2.ts = rech1.ts AND rech2.id > rech1.id)
```

By the way, you could replace that second `LEFT` join and `IS NULL` check with a `NOT EXISTS` subquery with same results and possibly similar efficiency (or even with a `NOT IN` subquery although that needs extra care for nullable columns, not recommended).

Comment: Great! That worked. Didn't know about `LATERAL`. It is a good learning for me. Thanks!

Comment: @ypercube `The duplicate results can be avoided in your method by adding a second condition besides the rec.id = rech2.record_id` What condition we can add here to avoid duplicate?

Comment: Why do a `left join lateral .. on (true)` rather than `CROSS JOIN LATERAL ()`?

Comment: @Evan because there might be rows in `record` without any related row in `record_history`.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ valid point, but he said he wants to get all the rows with. *" I want to get all the record's entries with recent record_history data."*

Comment: @EvanCarroll, sorry, I didn't mention clearly. I wanted all `record`'s entries even if there are no history entries for some.